# How to access contacts in Joomla via JTable?

Tags: database, joomla, contacts, dbo, joomla-jtable

Still working on my component, I am currently trying to add, edit and delete contacts. I found them to be located in contact_details. Accessing them using JFactory::getDBO() is working. The documentation says, using JTable is more safe and the intended way to work with the database.

Using JTable::getInstance('contact_details') leads to an error saying, 'contact_details' is not supported. Is there a way to access the contact_details using JTable? Would I have to create a custom table in order to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `JTable::getInstance()` is not the name of the database table it is the name of the table class. In this case if you looked in `/administrator/components/com_contant/tables` you would see that the table class name ins `ContactTableContact` which is the conventional pattern for tables in Joomla! where the first table gives the location (the API will strip off the `com_` the second says it is a table class and in either the table or tables folder (the latter is legacy) and the last segment is the name of the file.  So `JTable::getInstance('ContactTableContact')` should do the trick for you.